# pointer being returned from a function from an SDL library

Tags: c++, memory, stack, heap-memory

I have been following a game engine creator tutorial on youtube which uses SDL. I have been learning many of the things involved in C++ and have been having a deeper dive involved with pointers(raw and smart) as well as learning about the stack and heap. in the tutorial there is a small function that returns a pointer. What I am not understanding is how is this pointer still available throughout the execution of the code? Here is the code in question.

```
SDL_Texture* TextureManager::LoadTexture(const char* texture)
{
  SDL_Surface* tempSurface = IMG_Load(texture);
  SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Game::renderer, 
      tempSurface);
  SDL_FreeSurface(tempSurface);

  return tex;
}
```

this piece of code contains the pointers information throughout...

now for learning about this material I tried creating something similar to watch how memory works with pointers from a function I created.

```
int* test() {
  int num = 5;
  return &num;
}

int main()
{
  int* ptr = nullptr;
  ptr = test();
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  int testArray[5];
  int i = 1;
  testArray[0] = 1;
  testArray[1] = 2;
}
```

the pointers information gets destroyed when int i is called. Is there something that I am missing on why this isnt operating the same as the function above?

Comment: You are returning the address of a temporary variable. Once that function returns, there is no `num` anymore.

Comment: so does the function SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface essentially create a variable in heap, and return the pointer to said variable?

Comment: Look again.  Where does that `num` variable come from?  It isn't from the heap -- it is a local variable that goes poof into the night when the function returns.

Comment: let me try to rephrase my question, so i was trying to understand how tex isnt destroyed. so i tried to mimic the implementation in my own code, so does SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface essentially create a variable in heap, and return the pointer to said variable? (i should probably edit out my 2nd block of text so my question is more precise)

Comment: You didn't mimic the implementation -- that's the point.  You thought you did, but you didn't.  If you were to mimic it, you would have created a function that returned a pointer to a dynamically allocated entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `test()` breaks [this rule right here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/100157/).

I unfortunately can't find enough research to my satisfaction why this is a rule, but I will post my suspicion.

`num` is a local variable. Local variables are allocated on the stack. The minute the function finishes execution, local variables (i.e. `num`) are "popped" off the stack. That is to say, they are destroyed.

Variables that are allocated via things like `malloc()` or the `new` keyword are allocated on the heap. The heap isn't destroyed during the execution of the **program**

The address stored in num in a case such as this:

```
int *num = new int(37);
```

is an address on the heap. It is perfectly valid even after the **function** finishes execution. Thus, you can use it after the function finishes.

Comment: Minor detail: *are allocated on the heap* -> *are allocated in dynamic memory*. Dynamic memory almost always in a heap, but C++ is a very big umbrella and leaves the actual implementation details to the implementer. Technically the fluffy white blood of Care Bears could be used for dynamic storage.

Comment: Do I need to update my answer? If so, what do you suggest?

Comment: Keep the answer as simple as possible. Practically no one sees  anything but stacks and heaps. That said, something like *Local variables are allocated in Automatic storage, usually a stack.* and *...the new keyword are allocated in Dynamic storage, usually the heap.* is correct in both ways.

Comment: *The heap isn't destroyed during the execution of the program* Could use some rewording, but I don't think that, even if reworded, it can add anything not covered by the example that follows.

Answer (score 1):

In your `test` function, `num` is a local variable. It is destroyed by the end of `test()`.

You need to allocate an integer in `test` to make it work. In this case, the ownership of the pointer is transferred to you: you need to delete it.

```
int* test() {
  int* num = new int(5);
  return num;
}

int main() {
  int* ptr = test();
  std::unique_ptr<int> int_deleter(ptr);
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n" << *ptr;
}
```

Another example of returning a pointer is returning a class member. In this case, refer to the documentation on whether you're transferred the ownership. For example:

```
class A {
public:
  A() : num(new int(5)) {}
  virtual ~A () { delete num; }

  // `A` keeps the ownership of the pointer.
  const int* GetNum() const { return num; }

private:
  int* num;
}

int main() {
  A a;
  std::cout << *a.GetNum() << std::endl;
}
```

Returning to the `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` example, it is likely that a new variable is allocated in the method. You need to refer to the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface) about the ownership of the returned pointer (whether you or the library deletes the pointer).

Comment: that makes great sense, im more of trying to understand why tex isnt destroyed though? so does the function SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface essentially create a variable in heap, and return the pointer to said variable?

Comment: There are two elements here: the pointer `tex` and the `SDL_Texture` object `tex` points too. The `tex` pointer is destroyed by the end of your function, but the object it points to is not because it's allocated on heap.

Comment: It is not destroyed because anything dynamically allocated must be explicitly destroyed by some "deleter" function, whether it is `delete`, `delete[]`, `free()`, `GlobalFree` (from Windows), etc.

Comment: @twokdavey [read the documentation for `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface). You do not know what SDL did to allocate storage for that pointer so you cannot safely dispose of it until you know how to dispose of it. Once you do know how to dispose of the texture, you can call the function (hint: `SDL_DestroyTexture`) or wrap the call in a custom deleter for `std::unique_ptr` to automate the clean-up for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to others answer, SDL is C(not C++) API so it does not have RAII which means there is no such environment that automatically calls constructor and destructor.

You need to call [`SDL_DestroyTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyTexture) to free the texture. Otherwise it will cause memory leak unlike local variables.

You may conceptually think of

- `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()`(or other Texture generation API) as `new SDL_Texture`
- `SDL_DestroyTexture(texture)` as `delete texture`

Comment: In fact you could overload `new` and `delete` to do exactly what Hanjoung Lee says. However, I am at a loss as to how you would pass in the parameters needed by `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 basic storage classes in C/C++:

1. Automatic:
   Local Objects - normally created on stack - get destructed once the scope they reside reaches its end. The scope normally resides in a function body, therefore all automatic objects constructed within a function are already destructed when the function returns; this includes function argumemts too.
2. Internal/static:
   Their lifespan is longer than most automatic variables. Once constructed, they live until program finishing point is reached;  when they are automatically destructed. These objects are only visible/accessible in the nesting module(translation unit)/function/scope.
3. Global/external:
   These objects live longer than all objects in the 1st 2 classes above. They are constructed once the program starts and destroyed right before the program ends when all automatic and internal objects are already dead.
4. Dynamic/heap:
   They have flexible lifespan. They can be constructed anytime during program execution and destroyed anytime after. They normally need manual disposal unless proper smart pointers are used to automate management of their lifespan. One common source of bugs is to not dispose of them properly.

So normally, returning a refrence/pointer to any none-automatic objects is ok.